# Does the spell "Silence" affect the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, area-of-effect

While I was DMing a D&D 5th Edition game, one of my player's sorcerers cast the spell *Silence* while they were 5 feet away from an enemy caster. They centered the spell on the space that the enemy caster was in, and a round of combat finished. On the sorcerer's turn, they asked me if they could use a verbal spell while in the area of their *Silence* spell. Their reasoning is that they had cast the spell, so they could prevent it from affecting them.

In this situation, I decided to not allow it because it would unbalance the spell. But I want to know what other people would think about this.

Would the caster of the *Silence* spell be able to prevent it from affecting themselves?

Comment: Similar Questions: [Would a caster's AoE spell hit the caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60528/40363), [Can you choose not to affect yourself with area of effect spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69951/40363)

Answer (score 46):

### The Sorcerer is indeed Silenced by their own spell.

Nothing in the spell description excludes the Sorcerer from the spell. The only way to get around this is if the Sorcerer also has the *Subtle Spell* meta-magic skill selected so that they can remove the Verbal component.

Nothing about casting a spell makes you immune to its effects unless it's stated in the spell description.

Comment: Would this answer be different if they were an Evoker Wizard instead of a Sorcerer?

Comment: @nick012000 If you're referring to their Sculpt Spells feature, then it would only work on evocation spells, and _silence_ is an illusion spell, so that wouldn't work. This answer would be the same (excluding the Sorcerer-specific stuff).

Comment: +1 And even "get around this" using *Subtle Spell* does *not* mean that they are unaffected by the *Silence*: they cannot, for example, shout instructions to fellow party members because they are still affected by *Silence*.

Answer (score 4):

The text of the spell [Silence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) states that:

> Casting a spell that includes a verbal component is impossible there.

By the rules of D&D, all the spells can also affect the user and his allies if not stated otherwise; every spellcaster that would find himself in the radius of the spell would not be able to cast spells that require a verbal component.

This could actually be used at your advantage for countering enemy spellcasters; maybe your sorcerer has the meta-magic **Subtle Spell**.
Being the DM I would also allow the meta-magic **Careful Spell** to be able to target someone and make it immune to the silence spell, but that is up to you.

Answer (score -11):

### The Sorcerer is not affected by Silence

So this is my logic on this matter:

1. Targets are not limited to creatures.

   - The target in the **Silence** spell is a the Point of Origin of a Sphere.
2. *Targeting Yourself* states that if you are in your AoE spell, you **can** target yourself.

   - It does not say **choose** yourself, in comparison to "If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can choose yourself."
   - Choose indicates a choice, as in you must make a choice. In the case of a target creatures spell, that choice is how many creatures. In AoE, that choice is where the PoO is and it's orientation.
   - It is impossible to target 0 creatures with a spell that targets creatures. It is possible to target 0 creatures with an AoE spell if nothing is inside the AoE.
   - If you are in the Area of Effect of your spell, you would assume you are affected by it based on the AoE mechanics, unless if it was stated otherwise somewhere.
   - This means if the area is under the Silence effect, you can include or exclude yourself from the magic.
3. **Can** in this case can have multiple interpretations.

   - It is **possible** to include yourself.
   - You have the **ability** to include yourself.
   - You have **permission** to include yourself.
   - Given that this is the Designers telling us the rules on targeting yourself, I interpreted it as permission to do so.
   - Possibility is already thoroughly covered in the AoE section.
   - I don't see anything that directly implies one way or the other however.
4. *Careful Spell* and *Sculpt Spells* explicitly state **other** creatures. If you were not immune to your magic, why doesn't it simply state creatures?

   - Both those abilities imply you already have the ability to exclude yourself from your magic.
   - On the other hand, why would you be able to exclude other creatures from your magic and not yourself? That in the very least doesn't make sense.
     -In this case these don't matter since Silence does not require a Save

So **NO**, they would not be affected by that logic.

- Why would they need to tell you that you can target yourself in your own AoE, if from the AoE mechanics you already know that?

  - I believe that they are noting it is a option, not automatic.
  - In *Targeting Yourself*, the first sentence is for spells that target creatures.
  - The second sentence is for when you are inside your area of effect spell.
  - The second sentence does not directly refer to the first.

    - You can see this as it uses "**a** spell" rather than "**the** spell", which would be making an independent statement v.s. a dependent statement.
  - They don't mention spells that target objects since the caster can't be an object (as a player at least).

---

### Counter-arguments

1. In *Targeting Yourself*, Targets is being referred to in the context of spells that target Creatures only.

   - Nothing directly implies that the Targets are Creatures.
   - The section refers to an Area of Effect and the Target of an Area of Effect spell is the Point of Origin.
   - The spell *Mass Cure Wounds* has both an Area of Effect and a Choose creatures portion.
   - Area of Effect spells are defined as:

> Spells such as *burning hands* and *cone of cold* **cover an area**, allowing them to affect multiple creatures at once.

- The target at the end of the day for an AoE spell is the area, not necessarily a limited amount of creatures within.

  - Even if this is not strictly true, the first statement in *Targeting Yourself* already tells you that you can target yourself. Why say it again in a more ambiguous way?

2. Including or not including the Point of Origin is equivalent to Targeting or not Targeting the caster in the Area of Effect

   - The Point of Origin is the point from which as spells energy erupts.
   - Point of Origin doesn't matter when you are determining if you can target yourself.
   - The only relevant factors are if you want to and if you are in the area of effect.
3. The spell must state you are excluded from its effects, not the other way around

   - This is not stated anywhere.
   - I believe the *Targeting Yourself* section is there specifically to clear up this possible misassumption.
   - Further evidence is demonstrated in *Scourge Asamir*, **Radiant Consumption**.

> During it, you shed bright light in a 10-foot radius and dim light for an additional 10 feet, and at the end of each of your turns, **you and each creature within 10 feet of you** take radiant damage equal to half your level (rounded up)

- Why would this ability have to include this extra mention, where other Area of Effects do not?

  - The only reason I can think of is that the caster is inherently excluded from the effects of their spell.

---

TARGETS

> A typical spell requires you to pick one or more targets
> to be affected by the spell's magic. A spell's description
> tells you whether the spell **targets creatures, objects, or
> a point of origin** for an area of effect (described below)

TARGETING YOURSELF

> If a spell targets a creature of your choice, you can
> choose yourself, unless the creature must be hostile or
> specifically a creature other than you. If you are in the
> area of effect of **a** spell you cast, you **can** target yourself.

CAREFUL SPELL

> When you cast a spell that forces **other** creatures to make
> a saving throw, you can protect some of those creatures
> from the spell's full force. To do so, you spend 1 sorcery
> point and choose a number of those creatures up to your
> Charisma modifier (minimum of one creature). A chosen
> creature automatically succeeds on its saving throw
> against the spell.

SCULPT SPELLS

> Beginning at 2nd level, you can create pockets of
> relative safety within the effects of your evocation spells.
> When you cast an evocation spell that affects **other**
> creatures that you can see, you can choose a number
> of them equal to 1 + the spell's level. The chosen
> creatures automatically succeed on their saving throws
> against the spell, and they take no damage if they would
> normally take half damage on a successful save

**Mass Cure Wounds**
Evocation

> **Level**: 5 
> **Casting time**: 1 Action 
> **Range**: 60 feet 
> **Components**: V, S 
> **Duration**: Instantaneous 
> A wave of healing energy washes out from a point of your choice within range.Choose up to six creatures in a 30-foot-radius sphere centered on that point. Each target regains hit points equal to 3d8 + your spellcasting
> ability modifier. This spell has no effect on undead or constructs.

Page: 258 Players Handbook

Comment: The "Targeting Yourself" section states: "If a spell targets a creature of your choice..." *Silence* does not target a creature of your choice, so your basis for saying it is optional is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: "*But this is magic, so you shouldn't necessarily apply the same logic you would with a combustion explosion as in the case of Fireball*": maybe I am missing something, but are you saying that if a caster is in the AoE of a *Fireball* spell they have cast they are taking damage?

Comment: `If you are in the area of effect of a spell you cast, you can target yourself.` This almost certainly refers to spells that involve selecting targets within an area of effect, such as _mass cure wounds_.

Comment: The use of "can" in the sense above is "able to" which doesn't necessarily imply a choice.  For example, warnings like "standing beyond this point can result in death" or "touching a live wire can result in injury".

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I was mainly talking about the sentence after that, which refers to Area of Effect. Silence is an area of effect spell.

Comment: @Eddymage I removed that part since it was confusing and not really necessary

Comment: @shhalahr That's a fair point, I have addressed it. Thanks

Comment: @GcL That is true, but can has multiple meanings beyond able to, which could easily replace each other without contradictions. I have addressed this as well. Thanks

Comment: Actually, it was contradicting what you're saying. My question then is: if a caster surrounded by enemies casts a *Fireball* spell and the explosion includes the caster itself, is *Fireball* damaging also the caster?

Comment: Only if the decide to target themselves