# Does Cloud of Daggers affect the caster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, area-of-effect

New to 5e and this has been a painful rabbit hole coming for 3.5. I have a pc who wants to cast *cloud of daggers* centered on himself as a sort of shield to protect himself from melee attackers. I said that the magical daggers would hurt him at the beginning of his turn and he has retorted with several days worth of arguments saying that it shouldn't affect the caster.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. Thanks for the question.  The [Tour], the [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] provide further guidance on how to get the best out of this format. Happy Gaming! 

Comment: Related: [Can you choose not to affect yourself with area of effect spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69951/can-you-choose-not-to-affect-yourself-with-area-of-effect-spells)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### You are a creature.

[*Cloud of daggers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloud-of-daggers) states:

> *A creature* takes 4d4 slashing damage when it enters the spell’s area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there.

You are a creature, so you are affected while in the spell's area. The idea here is that *cloud of daggers* makes no exception for the caster, when other area of effect spells do. For example, [*spirit guardians*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spirit-guardians) says:

> When you cast this spell, you can designate any number of creatures you can see to be unaffected by it.

Unless an area of effect spell explicitly provides for excluding the caster, the caster can be affected by the spell.

Comment: I suppose it’s the difference between “can see” and “currently see”, no?

Answer (score 4):

#### Spells do what they say they do [(broadly)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret)

As Thomas Markov says, the spell doesn't exclude the caster, but it's also worth mentioning that, contrary to what your player is looking for, it also doesn't act as a shield. It doesn't say it provides cover, so it doesn't. It doesn't say it damages attackers, so it doesn't. The one thing the spell does is damage a creature in its space.

Comment: Yeah, the best you can do is cast it on the square in front of you, and hope that the enemies avoid that space to avoid getting damaged.